# Chrome doesn't hit breakpoint until I type debugger three times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For a while there it would only work if I typed debugger twice. It seems to be getting worse though. Now I have to type debugger three times. Any idea why this is happening to me?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you set breakpoints by clicking on a line number?

Comment: it's not doing it at the moment. i'll update if it starts doing it again. ..i never tried setting multiple breakpoints.

Comment: I rarely use the `debugger` statement, I just set breakpoints from devtools.

Comment: It started doing it again (only need two this time though). It does the same with breakpoints as it does with debugger;. e.g. http://imgur.com/sZNZrXj